# How to enable or disable landscape mode for specific ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, landscape-portrait

I have enabled landscape left and right modes in my Xcode.

How to enable or disable landscape mode for specific ViewControllers?

For some VC's I required landscape and for some VC's I required only portrait mode.

How to achieve it programatically in Objective C?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller, override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` property

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscape
}
```

You only need to make sure that you don't return anything that conflicts with the "Device Orientation" settings, otherwise the app will crash.